# J2ME: lock the device programmatically

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I am working in J2ME. I want to lock device programmatically. Only one screen (in which text field for password and one button to unlock ) must show. If user press END button then it must not work.

For example suppose my application is running in device(Mobile) then if any person get this device he must enter password, then he can use that device other wise he can do nothing(neither call nor anything).

Please suggest how can I do this.

Comment: You want a modal window or dialog. A search in your favorite search engine for "j2me modal screen" should turn up a lot of results. For instance: http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/how-to-implement-a-modal-alert.html

Comment: Mr. Pap please help me to solve keypad lock functionality. I want to show only one screen and user must not able to end that midlet. If he enters right password then he can do whatever he want. So please focus on locking functionality.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by "...focus on locking...". Have you done ANY research on this? Have you looked into system modal dialogs in J2ME? I mean, I could write the whole thing for you, but typically I charge for things like that. Now, if there is some specific problem you're stuck on (other than "how do I do X"), please edit your question and add as much detail as possible and perhaps someone can help you along.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to inform you, there's absolutely no way to do this in J2ME.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem.

This is the main code to solve this problem:-

```
 protected void hideNotify() {

        Display.getDisplay(myMidlet).setCurrent(null);
        super.hideNotify();
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

                Display.getDisplay(myMidlet).setCurrent(new LockScreen(myMidlet));
            }
     }
     );
     thread.start();


    }
```

I write this code into my LockScreen canvas. So only lock screen is displaying , if user press end button then it shows that lock screen and again.

Comment: right... and what does your `LockScreen` class do?  Also which device does this run on?  J2ME devices such as Nokia S40/S60/Sony Ericsson/Samsung all have hard end keys (usually coloured red).  Pressing this key will take you **out** of the MIDlet and back in to the native OS, from where you can make a call, text, or do whatever you like.  There is no way to override this behaviour.

Comment: Hey @funkybro as you know some device like as S60 support multi tasking so our application run in background even we press Red button.
So when our LockScreen canvas is visble and we press red button then hideNotify() is called , and I added a thread which is helpful to come our application in front. Hence our aim achieved...

Comment: S60 has a menu button, which when held down behaves like Alt-Tab, i.e. you can switch between apps.  It possible to force quit apps from here.  There is absolutely no way for a MIDlet to prevent a user interacting with the device.